# XLSM files get converted to XLSX file when downloading using pre-signed S3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are downloading XLSM file from S3 but it getting converted into XLSX file . we are using aws sdk[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkTzf.png)
[image]

Comment: Set the content type to `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12`

Comment: Anon Coward Thanks a lot